# Can I get the full result of Google's speech to text transcription as JSON from the php library?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

I'm using google's php api (https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php) for speech to text transcription and am getting everything to work so far. However; all the examples on using the php library show the results being handled like this:

```
if ($op->operationSucceeded()) {
  $response = $op->getResult();

  // each result is for a consecutive portion of the audio. iterate
  // through them to get the transcripts for the entire audio file.
  foreach ($response->getResults() as $result) {
    $alternatives = $result->getAlternatives();
    $mostLikely = $alternatives[0];
    $transcript = $mostLikely->getTranscript();
    $confidence = $mostLikely->getConfidence();
    printf('Transcript: %s' . PHP_EOL, $transcript);
    printf('Confidence: %s' . PHP_EOL, $confidence);
  }
}
```

I would really like the full result as json so I can easily store it in a database table. Is there a way to get the full result returned as json?

Thanks!

Comment: It should not take a Rocket Scientist to convert what you have to JSON

Comment: Like `foreach ($response->getResults() as $result) { $json[] = $result; } $theJson = json_encode($json);`

Comment: Of course not, but really, why reinvent the wheel where there (probably) is one function call that will return this. Also, those results are quite a few tiers deep resulting in a big mess of structuring arrays to convert to json.

Comment: Then it should be in the Manual and if its not them maybe there is not one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `serializeToJsonString()` on any object inheriting from `Google\Protobuf\Internal\Message`. Make sure you're using a relatively recent release of `google/cloud`.

Additionally, if you're only using Cloud Speech, [`google/cloud-speech`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-speech) might be better, as it'll install a much smaller package.

Comment: This was what I was looking for, thanks! I did only install google/cloud-speech and google/cloud-storage actually. I should've linked that.